# Каков лучший способ получить параметр аннотации в методе?

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Вешаю аннотацию, что бы указать методу запрос который он должен выполнить к БД. Аннотация такая:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface Query {
    public String value() default "";
}
```

Написал класс обработчик для этой аннотации, что бы получать её `value`:

```
public class QueryAnnotationHandler {
   
    public String getValue(String methodName, Class<?> clazz) {
        Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
        String value = "";
        
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if(method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                value = method.getAnnotation(Query.class).value();
            }
        }
        
        return value;
    }
}
```

И, собственно, в методе получаю значение таким образом :

```
String s = queryAnnotationHandler.getValue(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), this.getClass());
```

Нужно задавать `query` именно через аннотацию. Есть ли вариант получить данные аннотации более удобным способом?

Comment: у меня под рефакторинг сразу попал бы метод getValue и превратился бы во что-то вроде этого : return Arrays.stream(clazz.getMethods())
                .filter(method -> method.getName().equals(methodName))
                .map(method -> method.getAnnotation(Query.class).value())
                .findAny().orElse(""); 
ну а по поводу его вызова в рантайме я бы пошел путем спринга - при запуске приложения нашел бы все такие аннотации и затолкал в меп со значениями-стрингами(запросами). все таки рефлексия не быстрая. делать это в рантайме как-то не очень

Comment: спасибо за идею и отдельное спасибо за java8 стрим, не доводилось с ней работать, но код упрощает очень классно. Хороший повод взяться за нее

Comment: не за что. а что касается рефлексии, то упростить с ней работу можно разными способами. все зависит от того, что у вас за проект. к примеру, если проект на спринге, то у спринга есть своя библиотека для рефлексии, которая называется cglib. если нет, то можно добавить что-то легковесное, к примеру https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.12 это очень упростит работу с рефлексией, сократит код и избавит от типичных ошибок

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` весьма дорогостоящая операция, если это продуктивный код, то от этого надо избавляться. Если метод вызывается через CDI можно обрабатывать аннотацию в перехватчике, иначе, если есть возможность завернуть ссылку в Proxy. Если ни то и ни другое, да и вообще, я бы задумался, а зачем вообще надо это делать через аннотацию?

Comment: это для себя, изучаю что можно делать с рефлексией